# Firebase Functions: Error: Client is offline

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I just recently started using Firebase functions for the first time. When I was using Firebase Functions for Firestore, it worked fine but after I switched to Realtime, I've consistently been getting "**Error: Client is offline**".

[image]

It happens when I turn on node.js and run my application for the first time, and I .get() some data from the realtime database. [image]

When I click on the respective line at which the error exists, it shows me this.
[image]

This is how I initialized firebase-admin:

```
admin.initializeApp({
  projectId: <project id>, 
  storageBucket: <bucket url>,
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: <db url>,
});
```

Is it because I have the FIREBASE_CONFIG and GCLOUD PROJECT environment variables are missing error? I've seen a lot of different posts that other people are getting the same issue, but I haven't come across a proper solution.

If anyone has any solutions or if you need more information, please let me know!

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up. Also see: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen for sure. I'll do that from now on :)

Answer (score 1):

I have a feeling you may be hitting a race condition in the JavaScript implementation of `get()`. If that is the case, you can work around it by using the `once()` method, which should work exactly the same in this scenario:

```
const _dataSnapshot = await admin.database().ref('users').child(req.body.user_uid).once();
...
```

Comment: Thank you. That worked perfectly as soon as I used .once("value");